# SpriteKit enumerateChildNodesWithName with advanced searching?

Tags: objective-c, sprite-kit

The following code doesn't work as expected.  According to the SPRITE KIT PROGRAMMING GUIDE, pages 61 and 62 one may perform "advanced searches" by using regular expression like syntax, so, unless I'm misunderstanding the implementation, this should work?

```
SKShapeNode *myCircle = [self getCircle];
myCircle.name = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"CIRCLE_%d_%d", x, y];
myCircle.position = CGPointMake(10,10);
[self addChild:myCircle];   

// Lets remove ALL SKNodes that begin with the name "CIRCLE_"
[self enumerateChildNodesWithName:@"CIRCLE_*" usingBlock:^(SKNode *node, BOOL *stop) {
    [node removeFromParent];
}];
```

But alas, the nodes do not go away.  If I specify an exact name (like `@"CIRCLE_10_10"`) it works, but the wildcard expression `*` doesn't seem to, nor does something like this `@"CIRCLE_[0-9]+_[0-9]+"` -- not even if I use slashes `@"/CIRCLE_[0-9]+_[0-9]+"`.

What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT**:
THIS WORKS and I could implement regular expression matching instead of substring'ing, but hoping to get the Sprite Kit implementation working (ideally).

```
[[self children] enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
    SKNode *node = (SKNode *)obj;
    if ([[node.name substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(0, 7)] isEqual: @"CIRCLE_"]) {
        [node removeFromParent];
    }
}];
```

Comment: Looks about right to me. Try @"/CIRCLE_*" or @"//CIRCLE_*" and see what that gets you. Make sure the circle nodes are actually direct child nodes of the node (self) you're sending the enumerate/childNodeWithName message to.

Comment: That doesn't work either, tried that before too (omitting the asterisk) and playing with the slashes (from my perl regex experience).

Comment: Thanks LearnCocos2D; yes, they're child nodes of self.  In fact, in my first edit above, I show a block that does work while ref'ing self [self children] :)

Comment: and you're not still running the removeFromParent code fragment which for whatever reason now does work while you're still trying to find those nodes somewhere further down in the method? ;)

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your question.

Comment: [self children] enumerateObjectsUsingBlock works.  self enumerateChildNodesWithName doesn't.  In each, I've implemented the removeFromParent method.

Comment: I've re-edited my question, making it simpler :)

Comment: @LearnCocos2D I'm only running the removeFromParent within those methods and only in one place, I think that answers your question (now that I had a sip of coffee).

Comment: Seems like a BUG.  Reported to Apple as a BUG, case #15711721

Comment: I'm having this problem too. I've even tried getting the name of a child node, and then enumerating the children looking for said name, with no results... Hope Apple fix.

Comment: Use isEquaToString: when you compare strings. isEqual compares Objects  not strings. Discussion: isEqualToString compares each character but isEqual compares objects and return true if there are from the same class.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the following variation of your code in both the current and beta versions of Xcode on both iOS and OS-X.

```
    SKScene *scene = [[SKScene alloc] initWithSize:self.gameView.frame.size];

    for (int x = 0; x < 20; x++)
    {
        for (int y = 0; y < 20; y++)
        {
            CGPathRef myPath = CGPathCreateWithEllipseInRect(CGRectMake(0, 0, 20, 20), NULL);
            SKShapeNode *myCircle = [[SKShapeNode alloc] init];
            myCircle.path = myPath;
#if TARGET_OS_IPHONE
            myCircle.fillColor = [UIColor redColor];
#else
            myCircle.fillColor = [NSColor redColor];
#endif
            myCircle.name = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"CIRCLE_%d_%d", x, y];
            myCircle.position = CGPointMake(20*x,20*y);
            [scene addChild:myCircle];
            CGPathRelease(myPath);
        }
    }

    [self.gameView presentScene:scene];
```

All of your sample expressions work on the Mac in both versions of the SDK. On iOS, however, they only worked in the Developer Preview.