# enumerateChildNodesWithName:usingBlock: search expressions not functioning

Tags: objective-c, sprite-kit

This has been asked before, and I've been looking for quite awhile trying to find an answer, but nobody seems to have a solution.

Apple has this great method to enumerate through child nodes but it seems to only work for exact string matches.

For example, the Apple docs suggest that '*' can be used as a wildcard, or that [0-9] can be used in addition to a character, I have tried both and neither work.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsAnimation/Conceptual/SpriteKit_PG/Nodes/Nodes.html

For example

```
[tile enumerateChildNodesWithName:@"c[0-9]" usingBlock:^(SKNode *node, BOOL *stop){
}];
```

or

```
[tile enumerateChildNodesWithName:@"c*" usingBlock:^(SKNode *node, BOOL *stop){
}];
```

Apple Docs:
[0-9] This searches the node’s children and returns any child named A0, A1, …, A9. And using * The search matches zero or more characters.

I'm basically trying to enumerate all child nodes named c1,c2,c3,c4 without having to enumerate through each specifically.  It works fine, would just be more clean to have one enumeration I think.

Any suggestions, maybe I'm reading it wrong?

Comment: hmm don't you have to start the string with / like in "/c*" ?

Comment: That doesn't seem to help either.

Comment: Yup, no solution here either, exact same question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20711426/spritekit-enumeratechildnodeswithname-with-advanced-searching

Answer (score 3):

I contacted Apple Developer Technical Support about this. They confirmed this to be a bug and to report it as such.